# DNS server with filtering

Tags: windows, server, dns

I need a DNS server that will be able to filter out specific requests (with specific words) and reply with a preconfigured address.

Requirements:

- Runs on Windows 8.1
- As lightweight as possible
- No caching (or ability to turn off)
- Configurable filter
- If not matching filter, forward to another configurable DNS server

Nice-to-have:

- Ability to send hostnames to another program for analysis
- IPv6 support
- Wildcard support

Basically, very similar to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20286/dns-server-with-customizable-filtering-for-home-use), but without caching and with an actual answer.

Comment: Would you mind giving some example requests? In particular, do you want wildcards or grep-like features?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I don't know a lot about DNS, but I just need it to handle most of the requests. Wildcards is when you put * in it, right? That would be nice to have. I will add that.

Comment: So you are looking for a sofware that can intercept DNS resolution requests from your computer and then either block or redirect to another address. Am I correct?

Comment: @AswinPJ Pretty much. Also from other computers if they ask mine. (Say my computer's internal address is 10.0.0.5, and another computer has its DNS server as 10.0.0.5 on the same network)

Comment: @AswinPJ *poke*

Comment: @AmitGold Oh Hi.. I am not aware of any such software. Sorry. I was going to suggest you https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2015/05/18/applying-filters-on-dns-queries-using-windows-dns-server-policies/ but this works only on windows Server and Windows 10 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) will do all this, with the exception of IPv6 support.

the DNS server pushes an event whenever there is a request, which you can attach policy or event handlers to.  Policy can specify a particular IP for a response, or ignore.  If the request carries on, the DNS client allows you to specify servers to use for specific domains.

Policy allows you to run external processes, or even write looked up domains directly into an ODBC-compatible database or file.

WinGate has a free 10 concurrent user license, but DNS requests are not counted.  We also offer free support.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate

Comment: It is kinda confusing as to what I'm supposed to do to blacklist DNS requests... I currently have this Policy: http://i.imgur.com/CaHgXM8.png
for some reason when I use nslookup this happens: http://i.imgur.com/Q7a5mBY.png

Comment: Hi Amit, what do you have inside the first check.  Do you see the DNS request even hitting the DNS server?  I note that the server is ::1, which is IPv6, WinGate only support IPv4.

Comment: p.s. if you want to take this off line, we can pick it up in a support ticket, just send an email to support@wingate.com, cheers.

Comment: I switched the picture a bit, now YES points to REJECT and NO points to ALLOW, and here is the expression: Request.GetQuery(0).Name.Contains("blacklisted",false)

Also I think ::1 is just the IPv6 version of localhost, like 127.0.0.1 for IPv4.

Comment: I put a sample policy up at http://www.wingate.com/samples/DNS_policy.zip you can then maintain an actual list of blacklisted lookups.  The key is whether the DNS requests are hitting the server.  I think you'll need to set nslookup to use the IPv4 address of the DNS service in WinGate, and check bindings for the DNS service in WinGate to make sure it's available on that adapter.

Comment: p.s. IPv6 version of loopback is still a different protocol (IPv6 header etc) and therefore endpoint than the IPv4 version.

Comment: doing `nslookup - 127.0.0.1` works and refuses queries that contain `blacklisted`. Yay, thanks! Now I will need to test it from another computer, should be really quick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40371/discussion-between-amit-gold-and-adrien).

Answer (score 2):

[Acrylic DNS Proxy](http://mayakron.altervista.org/) sounds like what you need.

- It supports every Windows version from Windows 2000 to 10 (inclusive)<sup>[[1]](http://mayakron.altervista.org/)</sup>;
- It is very light-weight (just 428kB);
- Caching can be disabled with a setting in the [configuration file](http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicConfiguration);
- Requests can be filtered using a custom HOSTS file which supports wildcards and regular expressions;
- You can configure a primary and secondary DNS server which will handle any address not found in the Acrylic HOSTS file;
- You can configure Acrylic to log every host it processes to a file (which you can then feed to other programs);
- It supports IPv6;
- And, as mentioned above, wildcards and regular expressions are supported.

Acrylic can handle DNS requests from other computers as well, if enabled in the configuration.

**Note:** according to a comment on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/acrylic/), your Acrylic configuration gets overwritten when installing an update, so make sure to keep a backup somewhere.

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for, let me look into it, prepare for the bounty award!